# Use of archive files for compilation: why, and is there any alternative?

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, archive, glibc

In the middle of compilation, Linux kernel creates `liba.a` that contains many `built-in.o` and other object files from different directories, and use it as a major component of the final `vmlinux` linking. I have seen similar use of archive files in `glibc` compilation, and am now wondering why those projects use archive files and what would be the benefit for it.

As far as I know, archive files generated with `ar` are simply containers for individual files included in them. I do not see much benefit of using it other than reducing file search time for each of object files. Is this the reasoning behind the use of archive files in the middle of compilation?

If so, I would be surprised that file name search takes that significant to make kernel people care about, and I wonder how much the cost of not using archive files is, and if there is any alternative for the similar problem without spatial inefficiency of `.a` files.

Comment: It is easier to reference one or two libs in a compile command than 500 object files.

Comment: and you can add to .a incrementally.

Comment: @Duck Yes, it is easier to reference, but that is not THE reason, I believe. Kernel people are often very sensitive to temporal/spatial resource usage, and such usability benefit of archive files cannot outweigh the time overhead for archiving and twice space overhead of having archive files in additional to object files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: *I do not see much benefit of using it other than reducing file search time for each of object files.*

Your understanding of the benefit is not quite right. Archives reduce the workload of resolving individual *symbols*.

If you link a program out of many individual `.o` files, the linker has to consider them all at the same time. The references can go in any direction. The very last `.o` on the command line can call a function in the very first `.o` and vice versa.

This is not the case (by default, at least) with archives. With archives, functions in the earlier archives can only make references to symbols whose definitions appear in the later archives. (This is also related to the  the traditional Unix convention why the `-l` linker options go at the end of the command line!!! Your `.o` files first, then the command line.)

This means that once an archive appears which defines a symbol, you can be sure that the later archives do not use that symbol any more. Which means that you can remove it from your data structures. You are basically "done" linking that particular library; it has satisfied the prior references, and all that remains is to satisfy ITS unresolved references. If you order the linking process right, and the software is nicely layered, you can minimize how many symbols are outstanding at any time.

Linux is more than 20 years old now and its build system has a long and rich history, just like the code. Archives were not used originally; I think that started in `2.6` only. Also, dependencies were once generated by a GNU awk script.  People built the kernel on 25 Mhz 386 boxes with 4 megs of RAM, haha.

Archives are used today because there was a need for them with the kernel getting larger. It's not just for the heck of it!

Comment: I said "by default" because there is a way to make the linker take a group of archives and resolve them in any direction: the dash-parenthesis command line arguments. E.g.  `ld ... -\( libx.a liby.a libz.a -\)`.  The dash-parenthesis arguments enclose selected groups of archives. They are necessary if the archives have circular references. The GNU `ld` man page warns that this may have a significant performance penalty.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer about the linker internals! The distinction in the treatments of object files and archives looks interesting, and your explanation made me understand some of weird things I experienced with libc compilation (because it too uses a lot of archives in its compilation..)

Answer (score 0):

A few reasons off the top of my head:

To expand on what Duck sez:  the "link editor" ("`ld`"), a.k.a. "linker", ("`man ld`") takes a bunch of compiled object files (.o files) and libraries ("archive", as you call them) which can be "static" libraries (.a files) or "shared libraries" (.so files) and "links" them into an "executable" (a "program").  One tells `ld` which libraries to use by specifying multiple occurences of the `-l` options.  Imagine having to specify a few thousand `-l` options, one for each component `.o` file, instead of just a couple of dozens or fewer, one for each library.

Code relating to one area of functionality can be put into one library for use and re-use by other code.  For example, `/usr/lib/libcrypt.*` provides encryption capabilities, `/usr/lib/libssl*` provides supporting code for Secure Socket Layer, etc.

Also, I don't know which point in time Kaz meant when s/he said "Archives were not used originally..." but "archives", static libraries, were already in use as "recently" as 1983 (!).  I did not encounter dynamic shared libraries until the early 90s.

Comment: I think you haven't seen Linux kernel (or glibc) compilation process in depth. If you have seen it, you would have probably understood what my question intended. It's not about why libraries exist, but more about why linux kernel use them in its particular way.

Comment: It's entirely possible that I do not understand what "Linux kernel (or glibc) compilation" means, in which case my answer probably does not... answer.here's nothing magical about compiling or linking the kernel or glibc or any other library or executable.  The same principles apply.